# How can MD5 hashes be compared when logging in?

Tags: linux, cryptography, md5

Linux distros such as CentOS (v6.3 i.e.) are using a specific boot manager such as "GRUB", which contains a .conf file where you can edit your user information such as your password etc.

the password must be encrypted using MD5 (i.e. : Password --md5 kw485/fgf$&e), and that is a little bit confusing.

Assuming that the MD5 is a one way encrypting method and that encrypting the same string will always give a newly generated string.

How can the system compare the two passwords since they'll never match ?

here is an example :

```
grub> md5crypt
md5crypt
Password: hello
hello
Encrypted: $1$95Uz30$X/u7PX4F5GtEOsMguDDq10
grub> md5crypt
md5crypt
Password: hello
hello
Encrypted: $1$H8Uz30$LwAkSMZBYC07zJbx3lIVa1
```

as you can see we have inserted the same string and got two different results, assuming that's how a login scenario should happen such as :

```
$ login user
password : hello
```

- hello will be translated to `$1$H8Uz30$LwAkSMZBYC07zJbx3lIVa1` hashed
  password in grub.conf is  `$1$95Uz30$X/u7PX4F5GtEOsMguDDq10` that's a
  failed login attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Hash

As you say, the password entered by the user when setting his password is stored as a hashed value. A good [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) is:

- impossible to revert
- collision-resistant (it's very hard to find two inputs, resulting in the same output)
- but always yields the same output, if given the same input.

Let's assume your OS uses md5 and take your password example **hello**.
The md5 hash of hello is

```
echo -n hello | md5sum
5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
```

So the OS would store `5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592`

If the user logs in again, the OS will ask for his password and his input is hashed again with the same function, md5 in our example. **If the entered password is correct, the hashes match. Thereby the OS knows the correct password was entered, without actually knowing the password**.

But `5d414...` is not the string GRUB shows you, because in reality it's a bit more complicated.

### Salt

Assume an attacker has gotten the hash of your password.
To prevent an attacker from gaining your real password, the OS usually adds a random value to your password before calculating the hash. This value is called [salt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)), it is stored in unencrypted form together with the hash of the user password. Salting prevents [precomputation attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomputation), where an attacker would precompute a list of common passwords, store the hashes and then simply compare the stolen hash to this list. 
But salting does not prevent an attacker from brute forcing your password, by trying a list of possible passwords together with the salt value as input to the hash function and comparing the result to the stolen hash.

So in your example, the first time you entered **hello** GRUB added the salt `95Uz30` to your password

```
openssl passwd -1 -salt 95Uz30 hello
$1$95Uz30$X/u7PX4F5GtEOsMguDDq10
```

The resulting string is exactly what GRUB showed you, but it's not just the hash, it's

```
$x$salt$hash
```

where

- x is the used hashing function, 1: md5, for a more complete list see for example [Do all Linux distributions use the same cryptographic hash function?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120568/do-all-linux-distributions-use-the-same-cryptographic-hash-function)
- salt is the used salt value, here : `95Uz30`
- and hash is the resulting hash value

This format is not specific to GRUB, passwords in `/etc/passwd`, or `/etc/shadow` (see [shadow password](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Shadow-Password-HOWTO.html)) are stored in the same way.

Comment: can we assume that the MD5  hash code provided is an entry key to a securely stored binary string inside the OS itself ?

Comment: The hash should be stored safely, as stolen hashes can be used to brute-force passwords, but you couldn't enter the hash as the password itself, that wouldn't work. The hash would be hashed again, leading to a different value, which does not match the hash of the password, the OS has stored.

Comment: @YassineBenHamida no, the md5 hash is an md5 hash.

Comment: but how can we get a successful login if we keep hashing given strings and getting different results each time ?

Comment: But why do you think the os keep hashing the hash?

Comment: You set a password in the grub as an md5, when you login you write the actual password, the os hash it and compares with the stored hash, that's it

Comment: i updated my question and inserted an example of what i am actually meaning.

Comment: I think what is confusing you, is the salt I explained, in my answer. The string you see is not actually only the hash but:
$hash_type$salt$computed_hash$

Answer (score 0):

> Assuming that the MD5 is a one way encrypting method and that encrypting the same string will always give a newly generated string.

The hashing functions are:

- a one way function
- is idempotent: the same input produces the same output, and NOT a newly created string
- you cannot get back the input password starting from the output hash by a math function (only by a brute force attack)

The operating system compares the provided hash against the stored hash of the same password in order to check its correctness.

Comment: MD5 encryption does not give the same hash each time you encrypt the same "string" for example let's take a password jack if you encrypt it  you'll get kw485/fgf$&e if you retry the same thing you will get a completely different hash assuming that the password is the same, how can the OS compare both of these if we don't always get the same result.

Comment: "The operating system compares the provided hash against the stored hash of the same password in order to check its correctness." this can only be valid when using an encryption algorithm that adopts a key such as AES.